# php, get client ip address

Tags: php, client, ip-address

I have two php files in a same directory of a server (http://www.xxxx.com/php/),

1) **write_json.php**

```
    $address['http_client'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $address['http_x_forwarded_for'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $address['http_x_forwarded'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    $address['http_forwarded_for'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $address['http_forwarded'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    $address['remote_addr'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($address);
```

2) **get_ip.php**

```
    $json_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/php/write_json.php';

    $json_string = '';
    $ch = curl_init($json_url);


    $options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
                         CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'), 
                         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $json_string =  curl_exec($ch);
    echo $json_string;
```

**get_ip.php**    calls   **write_json.php**

if we suppose the client IP is : **76.2.35.46**   and the server one is :   **80.59.3.23**
when I call http://www.xxxx.com/php/get_ip.php  on a client browser

It shows me the Server IP not the client IP like this :

```
{
    http_client: null,
    http_x_forwarded_for: null,
    http_x_forwarded: null,
    http_forwarded_for: null,
    http_forwarded: null,
    remote_addr: "80.59.3.23"
}
```

How can I get the client IP instead of the server one ?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling write_json via curl from the server... that is, the server is actually requesting the write_json file, so write_json is seeing the request come from the server. Why not just use an include rather than a curl call?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible this way. You need to get the client ip first then send it as posted data to server via curl.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get client IP use following function that will return client IP

```
// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
   else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
   else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
   else
       $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
   return $ipaddress;
}
```

After getting IP in a variable then send